# Magento: using categories for brands

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, categories

I'm starting to build a new Magento site and its primarily focused on clothing brands. Launching with around 25 each one providing a range of products in categories. so some will have everything from shoes to jumpers, some may just be shoes or accessories.

Users need to be able to view a brand and see its categories for products, as well as via a different view view all of a type of product category so all shoes.

I really don't know how to set this kind of thing up. I know i could use categories for the brands then sub categories for the clothing categories, but then i don't know how linking sub categories items together would work (I've viewing all jumpers across all brands if they have separate parent categories).

Here'show the structure needs to work

```
Brand_1{
    Shoes{
        Item 1,
        Item 2
    }
    Coats{
        Item 3
    }
},
Brand 2{
    Shoes{
        Item 4,
        Item 5,
        Item 6
    }
    Jumpers{
        Item 7,
        Item 8,
        Item 9
    }
    Accessories{
        Item 10
    }
    Shirts{
        Item 11
    }
},
Brand 3{
    Shoes{
        Item 12,
        Item 13,
        Item 14
    }
}
```

So users can view brand 1 page, see items 1-3. Or view brand 1>Shoes and see items 1-2. Or view Shoes and see items 1,2,4,5,6,12,13,14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I chose to work this out was to create a custom attribute as a brand drop down to assign a brand to every item. Then I chose to create a custom admin module with a database table to store the brand details giving the ability to store extra information for each brand, that feeds into the attribute dropdown.